# Como carregar um url dentro dentro do modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ola pessoal gostaria de abordar um pouco como carregar conteudo (html)  de um url para dentro de um modal bootstrap.

Comment: Um iframe não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: pode ser, mas como seria?

Comment: Coloca o código do seu modal ai!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se realmente entendi corretamente o que você está precisando, mas seria assim! Pode estilizar com CSS o iframe para adaptar melhor ao modal!

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```